# window["name"] and window.name in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, properties

I'm a beginner of javascript. Here is my question.

Is there any difference between window["property_name"] and window.property_name in javascript?

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These forms are *identical* when `name` is a valid JavaScript *identifier*; in this case the property name is `"name"`.

The form with braces is required when the property name is an arbitrary expression (`obj[propNameVariable]`) or the property name is not a valid identifier (`obj["invalid identifier"]`).

All property names in JavaScript are internally strings.